# How do you use Amazon Route 53 to redirect a subdomain to a specific page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I would like to redirect my subdomain "subdomain.example.com" to a specific page on my site "example.com/specific-page" using Amazon Route 53. Is this possible?

I saw this answer and tried it ([Set up DNS based URL forwarding in Amazon Route53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53)) but that appears to only allow you to redirect to root domains, not specific pages on that domain.

Is this possible with Route 53?

Answer (score 2):

Set up Route53 to point to the subdomain. The rest should be handled by your webserver. 
For Apache, you can use .htaccess.
For NGINX, I'd set up the server and location blocks accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this is possible.

You could set up a DNS wildcard, so that *.example.com was mapped to a specific server, and then that server could use something like mod_rewrite to redirect from somename.example.com to example.com/somename.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually fairly simple.

- Follow the instructions outlined in [the original example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14289082/270949), **except  do not follow step #3**.
- Instead of following step #3 do this:

  - In the S3 Properties for *subdomain.example.com* select *Static Website Hosting*.
  - Select the radio button for *Redirect all requests to another host name*.
  - In the textbox, enter `example.com/specific-page`.
  - Click *Save*.
- Proceed with the rest of the steps as outlined in the original example.

Your bucket should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem by creating an S3 bucket, enabling the bucket for `static web hosting`.  On the `static web hosting` tab in the bucket, you can configure a redirect rule, set that redirect rule to `https` and set the redirect host to the desired address e.g.`example.com/blabla`

Then go over to Route53, configure a `A record` for the hosted zone, enable `Alias`,  and point the `A record` to the S3 bucket endpoint.