# Code: NoSuchBucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

So I've followed the instructions in [this excellent guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53) for setting up a redirect from `sub.my-domain.com` to `my-domain.com/sub`. I've checked and double checked my settings, but when I access `sub.my-domain.com` I get the error

> ### 404 Not Found
>
> Code: NoSuchBucket
> Message: The specified bucket does not exist
> BucketName: sub.my-domain.com

If I go to `sub.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` (the bucket I created) it is redirected correctly, and I am **100% certain double-plus confirmed** that the url in the CNAME Record Set is the correct one. What is going on?

It seems like `BucketName` in the error message is wrong, but why is this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's hard to tell since you (sensibly) obfuscated your question but the way you've written it, I think this is a case of not naming the bucket correctly for this application.

```
sub.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

If the web site is "sub.example.com," then that's not the correct convention, so I wonder if your bucket name is also not correct: the bucket should be named "sub.example.com" -- not "sub" -- and the web site endpoint should be sub.example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.

Comment: Why the bucket name must be sub.example.com?

Comment: @luyuan because that's how S3 is designed.  If your site name is "this.example.com" then S3 required that the content be stored in a bucket called "this.example.com". It cannot be a bucket called "this" or "example.com" or "mybucket" or anything else.  It has to exactly match the hostname, and it must be lower case.

Comment: Actually i have the same problem. I used s3 to store images, and the bucket name is 'seeyoukee.1'. Now I wanna use a DNS CNAME 's3.aws.seeyoukee.com' to direct. Is there anyway to achieve this without modify my bucket name?

Comment: @luyuan there is no way do this unless you use an external proxy server to rewrite the request headers and proxy the response.  S3's built-in capability requires the full hostname to match the full bucket name.

Comment: Is it possible to create a bucket 's3.aws.seeyoukee.com' and use 'Redirect all requests to another host name' feature to redirect all requests to the bucket 'seeyoukee.1'?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure what that accomplishes, since you will pay for each request twice and each request will take a little longer, since there will be additional time required to process the redirect.

Comment: As the s3 in Tokyo is blocked by China Government. It forces me to change s3 to another image storage service. The url is hardcoded in the App now. I would like to user a CNAME to replace the hardcoded url which can direct it to s3, and release a new version. After the new version released, I could transfer the images to another image storage service, and rebind the CNAME to the new storage service url.

Comment: @ Michael - sqlbot  Thank you! I had the same issue and I have renamed the bucket so matches the domain name, and now works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by renaming your bucket as "Michael - sqlbot" says.

But if you really want to keep your bucket name, then you can use CloudFront to forward requests to your existing bucket, and then use DNS to map the website name(s) to the CloudFront name.

CloudFront is another Amazon Web Service that caches HTTP requests to your bucket in caches all around the world, so your website will be faster :-).  But you will have to pay more :-(.

Comment: The AWS built in wizard will add the CloudFront option by default.

Answer (score 0):

in my case

> Code: NoSuchBucket

appeared because I tried to use js s3-client to copy folder from S3 bucket to other S3 bucket, instead of copying file and it doesn't support copying folders, that error message is very missleading!