# Amazon AWS - Configure a simple 301 redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-status-code-301, amazon-route53

I want to set up in AWS a simple 301 redirect configuration from my 'non-www' URL to the 'www' URL.

**example.com** --> *301 redirect* --> **www.example.com**

In AWS I configured Route 53 record set in this way:

*www.example.com --> simple routing to my EC2 instance*

*example.com --> configured as an alias of www.example.com*

In this way the redirect works fine, but if I check the redirect code with an online redirect check (like this [link](http://redirectcheck.com/index.php)) the result is not 301 but 200.

So, this is my question: How can I configure Route 53 Record set to make a 301 redirect?

Thank you in advance and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Route 53 does not handle web redirects. You can, however, do this with Route 53 and a S3 bucket. [Here are the steps to follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53).

In your case the bucket would be example.com.

If you want to use an alias (basically a root CNAME, even though a root CNAME doesn't work), the configuration to change is on your EC2 webserver. It would need to do the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I made it in a easier way by **creating a bucket on S3** named "example.com" (the same name as the to-be-redirect domain), then I set up "**Static Website Hosting**" property as "**Redirect all requests to another host name**" to "www.example.com".

Finally on Route53 I created a record set for "example.com", type IPv4, and I linked it to the Alias just created by making the S3 bucket.

It works!