# Fix SSL on AWS Static Hosting Website

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I had successfully setup DNS based URL forwarding in Amazon Route5 using this ref:
[Set up DNS based URL forwarding in Amazon Route53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53)

**S3 Bucket Settings**

- Bucket name: dashboard-mysite-com
- Bucket endpoint:
  dashboard-mysite-com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

Bucket static hosting redirection rules:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Redirect>
            <Protocol>https</Protocol>
            <HostName>dash.mysite.com</HostName>
            <HttpRedirectCode>301</HttpRedirectCode>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

**CloudFront Distribution Settings**

- Domain Name: asdfasdfasdf.cloudfront.net
- Origin: dashboard-mysite-com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
- CName: dash.mysite.com, dashboard.mysite.com

**Route53 Record Sets**

- dash.mysite.com.       CNAME  mysite-dash.heroku.com
- dashboard.mysite.com.    A    ALIAS asdfasdfasdf.cloudfront.net

So, https://dashboard.mysite.com was successfully being forwarded to https://dash.mysite.com. Until my SSL certificate installed on https://dash.mysite.com expired yesterday.

Now https://dashboard.mysite.com is ending up with error: NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID. (that says my SSL certificate is expired)

What do I need to fix the SSL certificate error on https://dashboard.mysite.com ?

Comment: ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID means that the certificate is not yet valid or expired. Can you please check start and end of this certificate against the local time on your computer and verify, that the local time is after the start time end before the expiration time?

Comment: Yes, I get that, so I have updated my question statement with information that I need to know how to update my expired SSL certificate for https://dashboard.mysite.com

Comment: There are multiple ways of redirection offered on the link you cited, some of which do not support SSL at all.  Please explain your setup more specifically.  Also have you examined the certificate visually through the web browser?  That should give you some kind of hint.

Comment: Added information regarding DNS forwarding setup