# AWS Route 53 / S3 Bucket Redirect All to One URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, amazon-route53

I'm trying to do the following with AWS Route 53 and S3 based on some other articles I've found:

oldsite.com/* to newsite.com/page

I'd like to redirect all of oldsite.com and any path to the single url of newsite.com/page.

Both of the articles below are close, but they give me the following:

oldsite.com/* to newsite.com/page/*, which will likely result in newsite.com/404

For further clarification:

I don't want oldsite.com/foo to redirect to newsite.com/page/foo

I want oldsite.com/foo to redirect to newsite.com/page

Referenced articles that are giving me to the /* to /* instead of /* to /static.

[Set up DNS based URL forwarding in Amazon Route53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53)

http://www.holovaty.com/writing/aws-domain-redirection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't explicitly configure the bucket to redirect all requests to another host.

Configure the bucket for static web site hosting, then create a routing rule that matches `403 Forbidden` (since S3 denies everything by default) and points where you want things to go.

```
<RoutingRules>
 <RoutingRule>
  <Condition>
    <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
  </Condition>
  <Redirect>
   <HostName>target.example.com</HostName>
   <ReplaceKeyWith>static</ReplaceKeyWith>
  </Redirect>
 </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

All requests should redirect to `http://target.example.com/static`.

Note that the leading slash is omitted for `<ReplaceKeyWith>`.

Comment: That worked great, thanks!  One small correction though, you're missing the closing element on <HostName>.  Needs the </HostName>

Comment: @ChrisDeal thanks.  Fixed.  Writing XML on an android phone keyboard... not recommended. :)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, it works perfectly fine!! Thanks! But why is the 403 condition necessary? Did not understand that completely.

Comment: @Yahya thanks.  The reason for 403 is that when you access a page anonymously, you don't have **permission to discover** whether (a) the object exists but you lack permission to view it, or (b) the object doesn't exist.  If "object present but unauthorized" was `403 Forbidden` and "object absent" was `404 Not Found`, that could arguably reveal too much information to a malicious user.  If you give "Everyone" permission to list the bucket, then the error would indeed be 404, and you'd need a rule for that, but it seems like a rare occurrence where you'd want just anybody to list your objects.