# Redirecting my website to another website in Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, httprequest, redirect, amazon-route53

I want to know how can I redirect my website to another website (through domain name or IP address) using AWS Route53.

What I have done so far is,

1) I have bought a domain name.

2) I have generated AWS Route53 Name servers (NS) for the website and registered these NS on the domain name provider.

Now, suppose my website name is `thisnewsite.com` and I want that when users put `thisnewsite.com` or `www.thisnewsite.com` on browser, they should be redirected to

1)some other website, for example, [www.flaticon.com](http://www.flaticon.com), or

2)some IP address like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, or

3)some IP address with port like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx

What is the Route53 method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) For URL forwarding, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14289082/902751

2) For IP redirect, create a record set of type `A - IPv4 address` that maps your host name to your IP address. This is an example (for EC2, but it will work for any IP): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html

3) For IP redirect with port: Route 53 cannot do that. In fact, DNS in general does not care about port. It only maps domain names to IP addresses. A potential solution would be set up a proxy that would redirect your request from port A to port B.