# Route53 redirect on Path but NOT top level

Tags: amazon-route53

We have a website where we need to redirect the path, but not the top level site. For example:

`www.mysite.com/myothersite` <- This needs to be redirected to `www.mynewsite.com`

`www.mysite.com` <-This **DOESN'T** need to be re-directed.

Can anyone help? I think it probably involves an S3 bucket but I can't quite figure it out.

thanks

Chris

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set up DNS based URL forwarding in Amazon Route53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53)

Comment: Useful links for you: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/ and http://www.holovaty.com/writing/aws-domain-redirection/

Comment: This is not something you do in DNS, which has absolutely no awareness of paths.  This has to be done on the system that operates your existing site -- which means that deployment or its configuration must in some way be modified.  Is that site currently using S3? CloudFront? Nginx? Apache?  Something else?