# Routing xyz.wordpress.com to abc.com/xyz/ through Route53

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, url-routing, amazon-route53, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi I have my website and it's hosted through AWS S3 and AWS Cloudfront and I'm resolving my domain through Route 53 now

I hosted my Blog site on Wordpress.com where I get my URL blog.wordpress.com now as I hosted my primary site on AWS so I want to resolve this blog.wordpress.com to abc.com/blog using AWS or Wordpress.com

Now problem is If I add my domain on Wordpress which is abc.com as a primary domain even after that it will route to my primary site .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set up DNS based URL forwarding in Amazon Route53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53)

Comment: No It's not as Wordpress is a site which need primary domain record set on their account I have my URL abc.com as a bucket but it's only going to resolve my primary site not the Wordpress one.