# Route 53 & S3 redirect 1 domain name to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, amazon-route53

I tried the steps here but they don't work

- [Set up DNS based URL forwarding in Amazon Route53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53/32991751#32991751)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14289082
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/

Objective: Redirect `a.com` to `b.com`. When you key in `a.com` on your browser, it should be redirected to `b.com`

Problem: `a.com` don't redirect to `b.com`. When I enter `a.com` to my browser, I see that there is no redirect to `b.com` and see the browser message `This site can't be reached`, `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`. The network response is `(failed)net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

`a.com` is a new domain name, `b.com` is an existing working domain.

Steps I took:

1. Create S3 bucket with the name `a.com`
2. Inside `a.com` S3 bucket, under `properties`, `static website hosting`, I redirect requests with the target domain `b.com`. I see an endpoint `http://b.com.s3-website-region.amazonaws.com`. Clicking this endpoint will redirect to `b.com`
3. Go to route 53
4. Created a hosted zone for `a.com`. The default `NS` and `SOA` records is created
5. Create a new A record, `simple routing`, routing the traffic with `alias to s3 website endpoint`, with value of S3 bucket that redirects to `http://b.com.s3-website-region.amazonaws.com`

What did I miss? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Are you directing a domain name (`a.com`) to a bucket? Is that part working? And you are trying to make `b.com` work the same as `a.com`? Please let us know what is working and what is not working, so we can figure out where to start helping you.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I just updated my question, hopefully it's readable now? :)

Comment: Are you saying that `b.com` successfully points to an Amazon S3 bucket, and your only remaining task is to have `a.com` use that same bucket?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, from what I understand (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/). The setup should be `a.com` => s3 bucket's (`a.com`) endpoint `http://b.com.s3-website-region.amazonaws.com` => `b.com`. Did I understand the AWS documentation wrongly?

Comment: That article is saying you should create a bucket call `a.com` and setup static website hosting to "Redirect all requests to another host name". Then, configure Route 53 for `a.com` to point to the bucket.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, exactly, that's what I want to achieve, `a.com` => `b.com`, using s3 bucket call `a.com` to redirect all requests to `b.com` with route53. The steps I took are as describe by the documentation. However, it don't work. That's why I am not sure what's wrong